# SQL Server query to get list of 2nd last working day of all months in a date range which includes holidays from a calender

Tags: sql-server

I need to write one query to fetch:

1. a resultset of dates. The resultset contains all dates starting 3 months previous to current date +  12 months next to current date (including present month). E.g:  Say Current date: 7/25/2018 Resultset should contain all dates starting form 4/1/2018 to 06/30/2019
2. From this resultset, the second last working day is to be obtained for each month.

*Condition*: The 2nd last working day should be a weekday as well as a non-holiday. The list of holidays is contained in a table called `RT_STATEHOLIDAY_MV`.

**RT_STATEHOLIDAY_MV:**

```
Description
-----------
01/02/17
01/16/17
02/28/17
04/27/18
05/29/17
07/04/17
09/04/17
11/10/17
11/23/17
12/25/17
```

What I have tried so far:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        1 AS DayID,
        DATEADD(month, -3, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS FromDate,
        DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(month, -3, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) AS Dayname
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
        DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate),
        DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
    FROM 
        cte
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate) < DATEADD(month, 12, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
) ,
wrkInd as 
(
    SELECT 
        (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CTE.FromDate, 1) AS [MMDDYY]) AS Date, 
        CASE 
           WHEN REFSH.DESCRIPTION IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS WORKDAY_INDICATOR
    FROM 
        CTE
    LEFT JOIN 
        RT_STATEHOLIDAY_MV REFSH ON CTE.FromDate =  REFSH.DESCRIPTION
    WHERE 
        DayName NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
),
secLastWrkDay AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE WHEN wrkInd.Date = 
--(SELECT MAX(wrkInd.Date) 
--from wrkInd where wrkInd.Date <=
(select case 
    datename(WEEKDAY,EOMONTH(wrkInd.Date)) 
    when 'Saturday' then convert(datetime,(EOMONTH(wrkInd.Date)))-2
    when 'Sunday' then  convert(datetime, (EOMONTH(wrkInd.Date)))-3 
    when 'Monday' then convert(datetime, (EOMONTH(wrkInd.Date)))-3 
    else  convert(datetime,EOMONTH(wrkInd.Date))-1 
end) 
-- AND wrkInd.WORKDAY_INDICATOR='Y'
-- AND MONTH(tab)=MONTH(wrkInd.Date)
--)
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS SECOND_LAST_WRK_DAY
FROM wrkInd
),
cutoff AS
(
    SELECT 
        secLastWrkDay.Date, secLastWrkDay.WORKDAY_INDICATOR,
        CASE 
           WHEN MONTH(secLastWrkDay.Date) = MONTH(EOMONTH(secLastWrkDay.Date))
                AND YEAR(secLastWrkDay.Date) = YEAR(EOMONTH(secLastWrkDay.Date))
                AND secLastWrkDay.WORKDAY_INDICATOR = 'Y'
                AND secLastWrkDay.SECOND_LAST_WRK_DAY = 'Y'
               THEN 'Y' 
               ELSE 'N' 
        END AS SECOND_LAST_WORK_DAY
    FROM 
        secLastWrkDay
)
SELECT * 
FROM cutoff
OPTION (MaxRecursion 700);
```

This works, but this doesn't take into consideration the holidays that are there in the holidays table.

Comment: Discussions about calendars, holidays, business days, and non-work days happen all the time. Just search the internet for suggestions about creating a real calendar table with the information you need (and beware your assumptions about work days - natural and non-natural disasters occur everywhere). And learn the lessons of the past. No one - **NO ONE** -  should be using dates with 2 digit years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are subtracting 1, 2 or 3 days depending on the weekday not respecting the holidays.
By the way, you are filtering out the weekends, so the cases 'Saturday' and 'Sunday' in *secLastWrkDay* will never occur. 
You can use a reverse numbering of the remaining days per Year/Month (and WORKDAY_INDICATOR) and pick out number 2 of the workdays as the one you want. Also, I suggest to not use varchar for date values. Your query could look like this:

```
WITH 
  cte (FromDate) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate)
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, cte.FromDate) < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) + 12, 0)
  ),
  wrkInd ([Date], WORKDAY_INDICATOR) AS (
    SELECT cte.FromDate, 
      CASE WHEN REFSH.DESCRIPTION IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
    FROM CTE
      LEFT JOIN RT_STATEHOLIDAY_MV REFSH ON CTE.FromDate =  REFSH.DESCRIPTION
    WHERE DATENAME(dw, cte.FromDate) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
  ),
  dayNumber ([Date], WORKDAY_INDICATOR, dayNumber) AS (
    SELECT [Date], WORKDAY_INDICATOR
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]), WORKDAY_INDICATOR ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM wrkInd
  ),
  cutoff ([Date], WORKDAY_INDICATOR, SECOND_LAST_WORK_DAY) AS (
    SELECT [Date], WORKDAY_INDICATOR
      , CASE 
          WHEN WORKDAY_INDICATOR = 'Y' AND dayNumber = 2
          THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' 
        END
    FROM dayNumber
  )
SELECT * FROM cutoff ORDER BY [Date]
OPTION (MaxRecursion 700);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one. If i understand you corectly

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Cast(DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS D
UNION ALL 
SELECT
DATEADD(day, 1, C.D) AS D
FROM
CTE C
WHERE
C.D<Cast(DATEADD(month, 11, EOMONTH(GETDATE())) AS DATE)  
)
SELECT
C.D
FROM
CTE C
LEFT JOIN RT_STATEHOLIDAY_MV H ON H.D=C.D
WHERE
datename(WEEKDAY,C.D) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
AND H.D IS NULL
OPTION (MaxRecursion 1000);
```

example on fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/52aff/24/0